# Example of $IJ\not\subset(I+J)\cdot(I\cap J)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals

Can somebody give me an example of a case where $IJ\not\subset(I+J)\cdot(I\cap J)$ for $I,J$ ideals in a commutative ring $R$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\mathbb{Z}[x]$, e.g. with $I=(2)$ and $J=(x)$, then
$$(I+J)(I\cap J)=(2,x)(2x)=(4x,2x^2)\subsetneq (2x)=IJ.$$

Comment: But why does it follow that $IJ\not\subset(I+J)\cdot(I\cap J)$?

Comment: because in commutative rings $(I+J)(I\cap J)‎\subseteq‎ IJ.$ if $IJ \subseteq‎ (I+J)(I\cap J)$ happens then $(I+J)(I\cap J)‎= IJ$  which that isnot ture. Notice $\subsetneq‎$ in answer

Comment: see this http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1438405/inclusion-of-ideals/1438419#1438419